# Pandas concat is adding NA rows unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm looping through a JSON object to create a dataframe. The JSON file contains a table of text with only 1 column in the table. I want to loop through each "row" in the JSON object, create a dataframe of that row, then append that row dataframe to another dataframe. I've tried both append and pd.concat and I'm not getting the results I expected. I'm getting a dataframe full of NAs and 2 columns instead of 1.

The output of `columns_name_list` is `['1']`.

The output of `row_df.columns` is `Index(['1'], dtype='object')`.

I've run:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[column_names_list], index=[0])
print("----------")
print("new_df:\n")
print(new_df)
print("----------\n\n")

for i in range(1,num_rows+1):
    print("---")
    print(i)
    
    row_df = pd.DataFrame(document_data["tableList"][0]["rowMap"][str(i)]["columns"], index=[0])
    print(row_df, "\n\n")
    
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, row_df], axis=0)
    print("Concatenated df:\n")
    print(new_df, "\n")
    print("---\n\n\n")

new_df = new_df.dropna()
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df
```

...which produces the output:

```
----------
new_df:

     1
0  NaN
----------


---
1
                                 1
0  EFG intercompany debtor- ABC  


Concatenated df:

     1    1
0  NaN  NaN
0  NaN  NaN 

---



---
2
                                                   1
0  As reported on 29 December 2003, the only subs... 


Concatenated df:

     1    1
0  NaN  NaN
0  NaN  NaN
0  NaN  NaN 

---

     1    1
```

The output shows that the `row_df` doesn't contain NA, but the concatenation results in rows full of NAs and has added an extra column unexpectedly.

Expected output:

```
----------
new_df:

     1
0  NaN
----------


---
1
                                 1
0  EFG intercompany debtor- ABC  


Concatenated df:

     1    
0  NaN
0  EFG intercompany debtor- ABC  

---



---
2
                                                   1
0  As reported on 29 December 2003, the only subs... 


Concatenated df:

     1    
0  NaN
0  EFG intercompany debtor- ABC  
0  As reported on 29 December 2003, the only subs...

---

     1    
0  EFG intercompany debtor- ABC  
1  As reported on 29 December 2003, the only subs...
```

For context, the JSON for the first and second row_df instances is:

```
{'columns': {'1': 'EFG intercompany debtor- ABC '}}
{'columns': {'1': "As reported on 29 December 2003, the only subs..."}}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: One idea is `row_df.columns` are strings and original columns names are integers, is possible verify it?

Comment: Please provide a sufficient example of the JSON to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've added the JSON objects that the row_df instances are reading from.

Comment: @jezrael The output of `columns_name_list` is `['1']`.

The output of `row_df.columns` is `Index(['1'], dtype='object')`.